# $(document).ready is not working when i put jquery library before body

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

**It is working**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button>Toggle between slide up and slide down for a p element</button>

</body>
</html>
```

But when i move

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Before `<body>` tag is it is not working, because i want  Put JavaScript at bottom, but i can't put document.ready part after jquery library, what will be solution.

Comment: your code should work regardless of where it is, as long as it comes after the jquery library.

Comment: *"but i can't put document.ready part after jquery library"* why not?

Comment: You started your post with "It is working"... Why are you trying to move it then?

Comment: @Kierchon : i want put Put JavaScript at bottom,but document.ready part is coming from cms

Comment: I understand that.. my question is why do you want it at the bottom?

Comment: In the case of a CMS system it's usually best to just leave it at the top, unless you build into your CMS a way to have it include all scripts at the bottom rather than just the libraries.

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: @KevinB yes i am agree with you but my boss want put it to footer

Comment: Then i guess it's time you build it into your cms, or explain to your boss the pros and cons of doing it.

Comment: @Kierchon because we are working on optimization

Comment: it is really good move jquery library to button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
       $("p").slideToggle();
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: @ParnitaDas Sure, make your script external, and user the defer attribute. note however it doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: @ParnitaDas i was referring to your comment, not this answer. This answer will work in all browsers, it's just that it will have to wait for all assets to load (all images, css sheets, css referenced images, etc) before executing your javascript.

Answer (score 4):

One: your code ***MUST*** come after the jquery library.

Two: If your moving the code to the bottom of the page, you don't need `$(document).ready(...`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button>Toggle between slide up and slide down for a p element</button>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").slideToggle();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you absolutely must have your page specific code above the jquery library, you'll likely need a queue system so that when jquery is available, the queue will be processed. Below is an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <!-- this would need to be part of the CMS header -->
        <script>
            window.initQueue = [];
        </script>

        <!-- here's your page specific js -->
        <script>
            window.initQueue.push(function(){
                $("button").click(function() {
                    $("p").slideToggle();
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <button>Toggle between slide up and slide down for a p element</button>


        <!-- cms footer -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.each(window.initQueue,function(i,fn){
                fn();
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why can't OP use `window.onload` instead of `document.ready` if Op wants to put the script anyways.. Though it is not needed since it comes after the elements.

Comment: he definitely can. i don't know why you would ask that.

Comment: I asked because of your #1

Comment: True, there's always *"another way"*, even if it's terrible.

Comment: I mean, it's not THAT bad, but it could actually negatively impact the performance of the application if the application is asset heavy.