# JQuery functions don't work. Ready handler included

Tags: jquery, html

This simple block of code won't execute in my browser for some reason. None of the JQuery functions execute, even with a ready handler on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
  <head>    
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">click me</button> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#btn').css("font-size", "1.5em");
           $('#btn').click(function(){
              $('#btn').hide();
           });
        });

    </script>
    <script src=
    "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type=
    "text/javascript">
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should include jQuery first before calling jquery functions.

Comment: Moving the JQuery import to the head did the job. What good is the ready handler then?

Comment: No, the ready handler as any other jquery code has to be placed after the include of jquery. You should either just include jquery first or you could change `$(document).ready(function){..` to `window.onload = function() {..` Detailed explanation e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326317/document-ready-is-not-working-when-i-put-jquery-library-before-body

Comment: I thought that the ready handler function will first wait for the whole document to load (including importing jquery), and then execute the function.

Comment: So be glad that you just learned something valuable :) In short - the ready handler can't work before jquery is loaded because the ready handler is defined in jquery.

Comment: Just to add, how can you expect an undefined function `$` to do anything? Until you have included jquery, `$` is meaningless

Comment: In the future, ALWAYS check the debug console for script errors as this would have pointed you in the exact direction of your error.  Trying to solve javascript problems without looking at the debug log is like debugging with a blindfold on.

Answer (score 3):

Have the .js file loaded before executing the jQuery calls:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
 <html>
   <head>    
     <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <button id="btn">click me</button> 
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" />

   <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#btn').css("font-size", "1.5em");
       $('#btn').click(function(){
          $('#btn').hide();
       });
    });

   </script>
```

Comment: Moving the jquery import up did the job, but what good is the ready handler then?

Comment: The js files are loaded in sequence, so assuming the script file was loaded before the use of `$` but that doesn't mean that all the modules are loaded and initialized.  The assumption is that you load your javascript core and plugins first.

Answer (score 0):

The "http" is missing in the URL to jquery.

Comment: This is intentional, to handle both standard http requests and those over https

Answer (score 0):

The ready handler is called after jquery is fully initialized, only then you can be sure all jquery features will do what they are supposed to.

Comment: This is not correct.  jQuery must be fully loaded before you can even set up a `.ready()` call (because `.ready()` uses the jQuery library so that library must already be loaded).  `.ready()` is triggered when the DOM has finished parsing and is ready to be modified and that's what it is for.